# If Len=3, move Cell Data 1 column to the left, loop through column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to move group codes out of their current column and move to the left 1 column. this is in a Macro because the rows will change based on the file/tables.
I've found an answer that seems as simple as the idea, but its not working for me.
The columns don't really change.

```
'Moving Group Codes

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Len(cell.Value) = 3 Then
        'Offset Paste (offsets 0 cells down and 1 to the LEFT)
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(, -1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next cell
```

> Error:  Run-time error '438'
> Object doesn't support this property or method

Code getting error:

```
Selection.Offset(, -1).Select
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Julie

I tried these codes: all fails

```
Selection.ColumnOffset(, -1).Paste

Selection.ColumnOffset(, -1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I'm sure I tried more, but they all failed.

Comment: re-pasting code to hopefully make it easier to read:

Comment: Seems like the issue is that you are referring to `Selection` instead of `cell`.

Comment: To copy the values to the column adjacent to the left, in the *IF* statement, you could use the simple `cell.Offset(, -1).Value = cell.Value`. If you don't want to use offset but a particular column instead (column `B` in this case), you could use `cell.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value = cell.Value` instead.

Comment: I recommend reading [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913882/16578424) and [How to avoid copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611707/16578424) - if you apply those adivses, the error will most likely be gone.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feed back. I will read those.
I did come back at this morning and must have had a clearer head. 
I was able to work through and get the results I wanted. YAY!!  
I think you are right about the 'cell' part of the code. :)

code:        
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If Len(cell.Value) = 3 Then
        cell.Cut Destination:=cell.Offset(columnoffset:=-1)
        End If
    Next cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning I took another look and found a solution that worked like a CHARM!

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Len(cell.Value) = 3 Then
    cell.Cut Destination:=cell.Offset(columnoffset:=-1)
    End If
Next cell
```

I couldn't be Happier with the results and simplicity of the code.